# Template specialization with nested unspecialized type

Tags: c++, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I'm having trouble working out the syntax for a nested partial template specialization. I think that's the right way of putting it anyway. What I want is an `as()` function which returns a casted value. In most cases `static_cast` will work fine so I have a generic version which does that, but in some cases I want to get specific. The trouble I'm having is when trying to return two similar templated class types, using a common `typename`.

```cpp
template<typename ClassType>
class Generic
{
public:
    // Constructors/etc excluded

    template<typename CastType>
    CastType as() const;

private:
    ClassType m_value;
};

// Templated version:
template<typename ClassType> template<typename CastType> inline
CastType Generic<ClassType>::as<CastType>() const
{
    return static_cast<CastType>(m_value);
}
```

That's the set-up. Actually I'm not 100% sure if that's the best way to do it, but it compiles in GCC and seems to work, so.. anyway. Now I want to specialize with another templated type (in this case, `Eigen::Matrix<T,4,1>` -- but perhaps `std::vector` or another as well might be used in time, i.e. to cast from a `std::vector<T>` to a `std::list<T>`) that's partialy templated:

```cpp
template<> template<typename CastType> inline
CastType Generic<Eigen::Matrix<CastType,4,1> >::as<CastType>() const
{
    return m_value[0];
}
```

Does this make any sense? What about a slightly different version where I take Eigen::Matrix of differing sizes and handle them specially?

```cpp
template<> template<typename CastType> inline
Eigen::Matrix<CastType,3,1> Generic<Eigen::Matrix<CastType,4,1> >::as<Eigen::Matrix<CastType,3,1>() const
{
    return Eigen::Matrix<CastType,3,1>( m_value[0], m_value[1], m_value[2] );
}
```

I know the above two code bits don't work and the syntax is probably horrible, this is what I'm trying to work out. Forgive if this is a duplicate. I looked at several similar questions but none seemed quite to be about this, or I just didn't see it.

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a method.  You *can* dispatch it to another function or class from your method though.  Code clarity drops considerably at that point though.

Comment: As Tom K says, this is just a case of a template function - you cannot *partially* specialize functions, only classes. You can however totally specialize functions.

Comment: I think I got ya, and I did see this sort of solution for other problems. Thank you, that helps. :)

Comment: You can also overload template functions which sometimes is better than full specializations. As others have said partial specialization of functions isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a function can't be partially specialize, we partially specialize a functionoid-thingy instead, and make the function simply use the specialized class.

```
//generic version
template<typename ClassType, typename CastType> class As { 
public: CastType operator()(const ClassType& b)
    {return static_cast<CastType>(b);}
};
//specialization
template<> class As<int, char* > { 
public: char* operator()(const int& b)
    {throw b;} //so we know it worked
};

//generic class 
template<typename ClassType>
class Generic
{
public:
    Generic() {m_value=0;} //codepad made me put this in
    // Constructors/etc excluded

    template<typename CastType>
    CastType as() const; //as function

private:
    ClassType m_value;
};

// as function simply grabs the right "As" class and uses that
template<typename ClassType> template<typename CastType> inline
CastType Generic<ClassType>::as() const
{
    As<ClassType, CastType> impl;
    return impl(m_value);
}

//main, confirming that it compiles and runs (though I didn't check b...)
int main() {
    Generic<int> gint;
    float b = gint.as<float>();
    char* crash = gint.as<char*>();
}
```

code at: http://codepad.org/oVgCxTMI
results:

> uncaught exception of type int
>   Aborted.